# React Native - No command found with name 'scrollTo'

Tags: ios, react-native-ios, multi-device-hybrid-apps, react-navigation-top-tabs

I am new to ReactNative, not sure what is happening here.
I want to use MaterialTopTabs of ReactNavigation library [https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator\](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator%5C)
Adding one of the property does not work with ios but on Android

```
<Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
        tabBarScrollEnabled:true // <--
    }}
>
```

Giving below error:

```
No command found with name "scrollTo"

-[RCTUIManager dispatchViewManagerCommand:commandID:commandArgs:]
    RCTUIManager.m:1132
__invoking___
-[NSInvocation invoke]
-[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:]
-[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:]
facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext)
facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const
invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_lane_serial_drain
_dispatch_lane_invoke
_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread
_pthread_wqthread
start_wqthread
```

Answer (score 0):

Reposting answer from [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32145#issuecomment-912973081)

The issue is with react-native-reanimated@2.3.0-alpha.3

Downgrading to `"react-native-reanimated": "2.3.0-alpha.2"` should solve the issue for now